# TFS 2013 Build - Newtonsoft.Json - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: json.net, nuget, visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild

**Update:**
So, I logged on to the server and opened the project with VS 2013. I clicked "enable nuget package restore" on the solution context menu. Now, it builds on the server. The problem is, I don't know how to do the same thing in VS 2015. There is no right-click menu. I have already enabled "allow automatic package restore" in Options.
-End update

I have a project in Visual Studio 2015. I can build and run it successfully on my local machine. It uses Newtonsoft.Json (JSON.net) which it obtains from Nuget. When I check in, and my continuous integration build runs on the build server, it throws an exception that it cannot locate the JSON.net assemblies:

```
The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

I have looked all over to see what is causing the Nuget package to fail. Is it because I am using Visual Studio 2015? Is Nuget jacked up?

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check the references in your project carefully against the entry in your packages.config file.

I had this same error and found that the project referenced Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.1 in its references, but in packages.config, the entry was as follows:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Changing the entry in packages.config to 4.5.1 instead of 5.0.8 fixed the problem.

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I discovered this by examining the local _work folder on my CI build server, and finding that the location that it was trying to pull the .dll from was not available in there; then I traced it back to figure out why. (Another possible cause of this issue is a NuGet package that has been deprecated. I had one of those as well that threw the same error.) I'm not sure how they got out of sync; this was a project that was originally worked on by someone else that I inherited.

Hopefully, even if this doesn't solve the problem for you, this will help somebody else down the road.